# gcloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am a new to Google Cloud Platform. I have setup a Google VM Instance. I am facing an authentication issue on Local Machine while running the command:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Can you please suggest some tips/steps to resolve the same ?

**Error Trace**

```
  File "/constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    table_data = datastore_fetch(project_id, entity_kind)
  File "/datastore_helper.py", line 23, in datastore_fetch
    results = list(query.fetch())
  File "/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/query.py", line 463, in __iter__
    self.next_page()
  File "/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/query.py", line 434, in next_page
    transaction_id=transaction and transaction.id,
  File "/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 286, in run_query
    _datastore_pb2.RunQueryResponse)
  File "/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 124, in _rpc
    data=request_pb.SerializeToString())
  File "/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 98, in _request
    raise make_exception(headers, error_status.message, use_json=False)
gcloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Other Info:

```
gcloud auth list
Credentialed Accounts:
 - user_account@gmail.com ACTIVE
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

gcloud config list
Your active configuration is: [default]

[core]
account = user_account@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = user_project
```

**Input:** (Standalone Python Function)

```
from gcloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client('user_project')

print(vars(client.connection.credentials))
```

**Output:**

```
{'scopes': set([]), 'revoke_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke', 'access_token': None, 'token_uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', 'token_info_uri': None, 'token_response': None, 'invalid': False, 'refresh_token': u'1/t-V_pZicXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'client_id': u'3XXXXXXXX9.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'id_token': None, 'client_secret': u'ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2', 'token_expiry': None, 'store': None, 'user_agent': 'Python client library'}
```

**VM Details**

```
Firewalls
Allow HTTP traffic 
Allow HTTPS traffic

Availability policies
Preemptibility  Off (recommended)

Automatic restart   
On (recommended)

On host maintenance 
Migrate VM instance (recommended)

Custom metadata
None

SSH Keys
Block project-wide SSH keys
None

Service account
service-account@user_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Cloud API access scopes
This instance has full API access to all Google Cloud services.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 12):

The behavior for application default credentials has [changed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes#12800_20160928) in `gcloud` since version 128.

One should use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

instead.

Note that changing credentials via `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud init` or `gcloud config set account MY_ACCOUNT` will NOT affect application default credentials, they managed separately from gcloud credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran these two commands:

```
 1. gcloud beta auth application-default login
 2. export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/<path_to_json>/client_secrets.json'
```

from local machine and it started working.

Comment: Glad it worked, but you shouldn't have to set that. What happens if you run `gcloud auth application-default login` and then unset `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Comment: For Windows: `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=keyfile.json`

Answer (score 0):

With the datastore emulator in local development I had to set the `apiEndpoint` based on the [Datastore and DatastoreClient docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/datastore/latest/Datastore.html). There may be a more elegant handling of this however this resolved the code 7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." errors in local development. (I'm using Firestore in Datastore mode.)

```
// nodejs myapp.js excerpt for config change running locally
    if(process.env.DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST){
        serviceaccount.apiEndpoint = process.env.DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST;
    }
    const datastore = new Datastore(serviceaccount);

$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=./emulator-data/
    ....
    [datastore] API endpoint: http://localhost:8081
    [datastore] If you are using a library that supports the DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:
    [datastore]
    [datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081
    [datastore]
    [datastore] Dev App Server is now running.

$ export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081 && MYHOST='http://localhost:8111' ndb node myapp.js
```